# Have GitHub Pages render gh-pages branch rather than Jekyll content on master branch

Tags: git, github, jekyll

I'm doing something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835937/how-do-i-push-jekyll-site-directory-to-gh-pages-branch-and-leave-the-source-in) here -- https://github.com/cpsievert/knitr-jekyll

However, it seems as though GitHub Pages is rendering the master branch instead of the gh-pages branch. Is there anyway to ensure GitHub Pages will prefer gh-pages over master?

Comment: For project pages it should use `gh-pages` by default. (It does use `master` for user and organization sites, but that doesn't look like what you're doing.) What makes you think it is using `master` instead of `gh-pages`?

Comment: The styling is messed up -- http://cpsievert.github.io/knitr-jekyll/

When I preview locally it looks fine, but I might have messed something up...looking into it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't the result of GitHub Pages rendering the wrong branch, but a result of the URL that it renders it on. Your CSS link should be `css/main.css`, not `/css/main.css`.

The leading `/` causes the browser to request `http://cpsievert.github.io/css/main.css` while it should be looking for `http://cpsievert.github.io/knitr-jekyll/css/main.css`.

**Edit:** There is no way to specify the branch you wish to use with GitHub Pages. From [the documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/):

> **User & Organization Pages** live in a special repository dedicated to GitHub Pages files. You will need to name this repository with the account name, e.g. [atmos/atmos.github.io](https://github.com/atmos/atmos.github.io).
>
> - You must use the `username.github.io` naming scheme.
> - Content from the `master` branch will be used to build and publish your GitHub Pages site.
>
> …
>
> Project Pages are similar to User and Organization Pages, with a few slight differences:
>
> - The `gh-pages` branch is used to build and publish Project Pages sites.

Comment: Ah, yes, I didn't set the `baseurl` variable properly...https://github.com/cpsievert/knitr-jekyll/commit/88a78e4c9525107eedfedc81cbab338d0cd907d1

Comment: I've accepted this as the correct answer, but I'd still be interested in learning how to specify master/gh-pages rendering preferences for username.github.io repositories

Comment: @Carson, understood. I have updated my answer to explain that this isn't currently possible.